# How to set a JComboBox's selected item from my JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jcombobox

i'm having trouble trying to set values on a `JComboBox` while i click the row on my `JTable`.
The Problem is: the code seems pretty correct to me, but still, it doesn't set any value to the `JComboBox`.

Here's what i'm using to try it:

```
    String s = Table.getValueAt(Table.getSelectedRow(),1).toString();

    Object a = s;

    ComboBox.setSelectedItem(a);
```

But first, allow me to give you some detail about the code:

I'm using MySQL as database to store the values, and filling the `JTable` from objects that i get from the database, that's why i have set the `JComboBox` to use `< Object >` as parameter.

That's it guys, thanks in advance. Looking forward to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! this is not correct because [`TableModel::getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)) return an `Object` and not a `String`, so you should to get the value like this :

```
Object obj = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
comboBox.setSelectedItem(obj);
```

---

If the valueAt cell `(table.getSelectedRow(), 1)` is of a `String` type then you can cast it like this :

```
String str = (String) obj;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work either, the combobox stays untouched when i click the row :/